# Al adjuntar documento, ¿Que se necesita para que archivos pesados, se puedan adjuntar? MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fileupload

Estoy trabajando con MVC C#, y cuando subo archivos pesados, me sale error.

En la webconfig tengo lo siguiente:

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Pero me gustaría saber, que parámetros o lineas de código debo incluir para permitir que archivos pesados puedan ser adjuntados.

**Observación: el input lo tengo definido para subir multiples archivos:**

```
<input id="file_es" name="file" class="adjunto form-control" type="file" multiple data-show-upload="false">
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En el mismo archivo `Web.config` debes agregar estas líneas:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000" /> <!-- Límite de 200 MiB -->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webserver>
```